# My code works in Firefox and Edge but not Chrome, where am I going wrong?

Tags: html, css

I have some code which works in Firefox and Edge but not in Chrome, please can anyone help to point out what I am doing wrong.

They are supposed to be three boxes that sit along side each other across the full width of the div.

Here is how it renders in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfsfv.jpg), and here is [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riPlL.jpg).

Very new to coding so I expect I'm missing something very obvious...

```css
div.img2 {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 5px;
}

div.img2:hover {
    border: 1px solid #72bf44;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=25);
}
div.img2 img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto
}

div.desc2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper2{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper2">
<div class="img2" style="padding: 20px;"><a href="http://www.carritech.com/contact-us/general-enquiries/">
<img src="http://www.carritech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Enquiry.png" alt="General Enquiries" width="526px" height="526px" />
</a>
<div class="desc2">
<h3><strong><a href="http://www.carritech.com/contact-us/general-enquiries/">General Enquiries</a></strong></h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="img2" style="padding: 20px;"><a href="http://www.carritech.com/request-a-quote/">
<img src="http://www.carritech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Quote.png" alt="Request a Quote" width="526px" height="526px" />
</a>
<div class="desc2">
<h3><strong><a href="http://www.carritech.com/request-a-quote/">Request a Quote</a></strong></h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="img2" style="padding: 20px;"><a href="http://www.carritech.com/telecommunications-company-information/feedback/">
<img src="http://www.carritech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Feedback.png" alt="Customer Feedback" width="526px" height="526px" />
</a>
<div class="desc2">
<h3><strong><a href="http://www.carritech.com/telecommunications-company-information/feedback/">Leave Feedback</a></strong></h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code itself looks fine, but what I find with Chrome is that it sometimes has issues with `div.class` classes. try changing `div.img` to simply `.img`, that might help. Also refreshing with ctrl+F5 rather than just 'refresh' forces Chrome to load the latest version of your stylesheet. That might also help

Comment: Working for me as well

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me and for your help. 

I have tried your suggestion of changing from the div.img to just .img as well as viewing in a private window however, altough it definately improved the result by now moved the div's on to the same line, the images are still distorted and stretched on Chrome.

Could it be something to do with the dimensions of the image files themselves?

Thanks again

Comment: I seem to have resolved this now.

I added max-height and max-width values to the .img div's and added     display: table; to the .wrapper div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working fine on chrome too, you should clear the cache or open in private window is my guess:

[image]